# PowerShell script for list users, role, and add users to Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql, azure, powershell

could you please help me create PowerShell script for create user on Azure SQL DB, and show list role and user which are in the database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a PowerShell script demo.

You can achieve what you want to do by modify the `$SqlCmd.commandtext` statements.

```
$Database   = 'Database'
$Server     = '"servername.database.windows.net"'
$UserName   = 'username'
$Password   = 'password'

$SqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$SqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = False; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"

$SqlConn.open()

#Execute Statement Method One
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.connection = $SqlConn
$SqlCmd.commandtext = 'delete top(1) from dbo.B'
$SqlCmd.executenonquery()

#Execute Statement Method Two
$SqlCmd = $SqlConn.CreateCommand()
$SqlCmd.commandtext = 'delete top(1) from dbo.B'
$SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()

#Execute Statement: Query Disply
$SqlCmd.commandtext = 'select name,recovery_model_desc,log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases'
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$set = New-Object data.dataset
$SqlAdapter.Fill($set)
$set.Tables[0] | Format-Table -Auto

#Close The Connection
$SqlConn.close()
```

The statements about create Azure Databsae users, you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins#non-administrator-users).

Hope this can helps you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
But I don't understand what this section is doing.

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.connection = $SqlConn
$SqlCmd.commandtext = 'delete top(1) from dbo.B'
$SqlCmd.executenonquery()

And what should I put in the value "dbo.B".

Thank you again for your help. Have a nice day.

Comment: @ВиталийНовиков You're welcome, I'm glad that could help you. Create the SqlCommand object and connect to $SqlConn, use the $SqlCmd.commandtext property to input your SQL statement. For example:   $SqlCmd.commandtext = 'create user dba for login dba with default_schema=dbo'. Then execute the statements by  $SqlCmd.executenonquery() or $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar(). You can connect  your Azure SQL database with SSMS and check if the statements executed successfully.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Leon Yue . Maybe you have a script for add several or all Azure SQL databases  a user or users. Thanks

Comment: @ВиталийНовиков I'm so sorry that I don't have the script such like that. If my answer really helped you, please accept it, thanks very much!

Comment: Hi @Leon Yue . Look the my script I think I solved my issue)

Comment: How I can add the form my code? hahahaahha)))))))))))))
`

Comment: @ВиталийНовиков What's your meaning? Use  $SqlCmd.commandtext="you sql statements". Did you solve your issue now?

Comment: Hi @Leon Yue and all, i have some little question, how i can export my list db to *.csv file. (use MS SQL Query)Thanks –

Comment: And hi I can hidden my password? Thanks

Comment: @ВиталийНовиков Of course you can. You can use many kinds of way to export your query result to a csv file. Such as bcp utility and sqlcmd. Here's a link shows you same [demos](https://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-bcp-sqlcmd-csv.htm) and can help you. For your second question, It's really a good question and I don't know if we can hidden the password. I never tried that. I didn't find any info about it.

Comment: Hi @ Leon Yue, Thank you so mach)) Can you help me, maybe you know, how i can write cycle at powershell to search servers and search databases, when i enter database name. Thanks.))

Comment: powershell script to list the available databases from multiple servers

Comment: @ВиталийНовиков If you still have other questions, I suggest you post a new question on stack overflow. Then not only me but also others all could help you. As you know comment can not answer you in detail. Thanks for accept my answer and have a good day !